# Compare 3 arrays c++ [like graph]

Tags: c++, arrays

can any one help me about this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main () {



int A[100] , B[100] , C[100];

int i=0 ,j=0, h=0;

int connctive=0 ;

cout << "THE PROGRAM TAKE 3 GRAGHS ONLY\n";


cout << "\n enter the Graph 1 \n";
cin >> A[i];

cout << "\n enter the Graph 2 \n";

cin >> B[j];

cout << "\n enter the Graph 3 \n";
cin >> C[h];

for(i=0;i<=100;i++ ){

for (j=0;j<=100;j++){

        for(h=0;h<=100;h++){

            if (A[i]==B[j]) {
                connctive = connctive +1;}

            if (A[i]==C[h]){
                connctive = connctive +1;}

            if (B[j]==C[h]){
                connctive = connctive +1;
            } else
       { if (A[i]!=B[j]!=C[h])
           cout << "non of graphs is connective" <<endl;}}}
}




cout << connctive <<"connctive " <<endl;



return 0;

}
```

i'm working to solve this program i want to Compare 3 arrays and print out the Union numbers with name connective or not Can someone please explain to me why the output from the following code is saying that arrays are not connective all the time :( ?? even when i entered different numbers

Comment: You can't access index 100 when the size is 100.

Comment: Don't make you loops go past the end of the array?

Comment: still there is problem :(

Answer (score 0):

As chris said, your loops

```
for(i=0;i<=100;i++ )
```

Should almost definitely be

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++ )
```

It may not completely solve your issue, but it's a start.

Comment: still print out ""non of graphs is connective"" 2465400 times even the numbers are the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I will make no assumption about what problem your code is supposed to cope with. But there is at least three problems in your code.

First, you better check your array bounds because your have a buffer overflow which always leads to troubles. In C/C++, array are zero-indexed, therefore when you declare `A[100]` you have 100 elements ranging from `A[0]` to `A[99]`. Your three loops are wrongs, stop condition must be `i<100` instead of `i<=100`.

Second, your last check is not what you think it is. You are not comparing three integers together. You are comparing a mix of integer and boolean promoted to integer, since the first `==` will return a boolean and it will be promoted to resolve the next `==`. You must write `(A[i]!=B[j])&&(B[j]!=C[h])` instead.

Third, you are not filling all vectors but only the first element of each. You must check the content of your data before you process it.

Comment: yah i fix this issue but still print out ""non of graphs is connective"" :(

Comment: Have you checked your three vectors? Are they properly filled with the data you expect? Could you tell us if your testes must be sequential or are they dichotomic?

Comment: Print your three vectors, check out the components to see that only the firsts are filled the others are random garbage from RAM (you have neither initialized them nor filled). Then try to execute step by step your program. Finally check your conditions which are not what you think they are. My guess: you have not nested them properly or maybe you are not solving the right problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are making some very basic mistakes like not even taking the iput correctly ,not checking runtime errors like the one by accessing an array element out of bounds.

I suggest that you should debug your code properly before you post here.

As far as the answer to your code is concerned, this is gonna be the algo..
**************************************LOGIC**********************************************

First of all sort all the three arrays.

Secondly pick up the first element of any array (say C), and compare it the second one (say B) until you find a number in B which is greater than or equal to C[0].If they are equal start finding the number in A (if you find any such number it is connctive) else take the next element of C.

*****************************LOGIC ENDS**********************************

*******************************CODE**************************************************

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void sort_array(int * X);

int main() 

{

    int A[5] , B[5] , C[5];

    int i=0,j,h;

    cout << "THE PROGRAM TAKES 3 GRAGHS ONLY\n";

    cout << "\n enter the Graph 1 \n";
    for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
        cin >> A[i];


    cout << "\n enter the Graph 2 \n";
    for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
        cin >> B[i];    


    cout << "\n enter the Graph 1 \n";
    for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
        cin >> C[i];

    sort_array(A);
    sort_array(B);
    sort_array(C);


    i=0;
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        for(h=0;h<5;h++)
        {
            if (C[j]<=B[h]) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (C[j]==B[h])
        {
            for(; i<5 ;i++)
            {
                if(A[i]>=C[j])
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(A[i]==C[j])
            {
                cout<<"\n  "<<A[i]<<"  connective\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

void sort_array(int * X)

{

    for( int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
    {
         for( int j=0; j<5-i ; j++)
        {
            if(X[i]>X[i+1])
            {
                swap(X[i],X[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

******************************CODE ENDS**************************************
```

Comment: @JAD let me know if you get any problem with it and change the "5" to a "100" as per your need.. ;)

Comment: this is the problem i don't know how i explain it .. i need program that return the connectivity number of an input simple graph like the pic in link ^

Comment: im35.gulfup.com/q8ksu.jpg << there are three graphs unconnected